# error in aspx page. You can only have one <title> element within the <head> element

Tags: asp.net

net site with master and child pages. I am generating title via .cs code file on each child page. It works fine on the desktop. However, when I try to browse via mobile, it throws the above error.  Below is code for master page.

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="xyz.SiteMaster" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" >

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

****child page code behind ***

```html
        public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            HtmlTitle title = new HtmlTitle();        
            title.Text = "child page title";           
            Header.Controls.Add(title);
       
        }
    }
```

*** child page ****

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="childpage.aspx.cs" Inherits="xyz._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

what is the best way to handle this. Appreciate your thoughts on this.